# MongoDB query in PHP different collections, same entry, different types, result on a null

Tags: php, mongodb, int, double

I'm actually working on a web server, I need to look for `CardNumber` in my `client` collection.

In order to do that, I get all the `Bills` where I can find my `CardNumber`

The problem is : in `Bills`, `CardNumber` are **Int64**, but in `client`, `CardNumber` are **double**. In PHP my query doesn't work, but when i'm doing it on mongo it works.

Here is my code

```
foreach ($this->bills as $bill)
    {
        $query = [
             //Already tried to cast, floatvar etc...
            'CARDNUM' => doublevar(($bill['CARDNUM']))
        ];
        $result = $collection->findOne($query);
        var_dump($result); //Always null
    }
```

For exemple, my first `$bill['CARDNUM']` gives me **0123456**

If I do this `db.getCollection('clientCollec').find({"CARDNUM" : 0123456})` in a mongoShell, I have a result.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem, the error was the name of `clientCollec` in my code ...